# mysql jdbc driver NumberFormatException

Tags: mysql, scala, jdbc, playframework, slick

I was trying to deploy my app which uses play (scala) + play-slick at Heroku, using [clearDB](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb) and I'm getting the following error:

```
2015-12-18T22:31:12.042179+00:00 app[web.1]: java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: Timeout after 1000ms of waiting for a connection.
2015-12-18T22:31:12.042430+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.getConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:227)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.042512+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.getConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:182)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.042589+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:93)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.042666+00:00 app[web.1]:    at slick.jdbc.hikaricp.HikariCPJdbcDataSource.createConnection(HikariCPJdbcDataSource.scala:12)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.042743+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.slick.evolutions.internal.DBApiAdapter$DatabaseAdapter.getConnection(DBApiAdapter.scala:56)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.042854+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.slick.evolutions.internal.DBApiAdapter$DatabaseAdapter.getConnection(DBApiAdapter.scala:59)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.042930+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.databaseEvolutions(EvolutionsApi.scala:119)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.043000+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.scripts(EvolutionsApi.scala:97)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.043071+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.scripts(EvolutionsApi.scala:112)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.043825+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.evolutions.DefaultEvolutionsApi.scripts(EvolutionsApi.scala:77)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.043946+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions$$anonfun$play$api$db$evolutions$ApplicationEvolutions$$runEvolutions$1.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:50)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.044049+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions.withLock(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:98)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.044123+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions.play$api$db$evolutions$ApplicationEvolutions$$runEvolutions(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:49)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.044241+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions$$anonfun$start$1.apply(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:42)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.044318+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions$$anonfun$start$1.apply(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:42)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.044416+00:00 app[web.1]:    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:594)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.044487+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions.start(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:42)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.044623+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions.<init>(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:149)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.044721+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get$lzycompute(EvolutionsModule.scala:53)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.044797+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get(EvolutionsModule.scala:53)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.044902+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get(EvolutionsModule.scala:44)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.044976+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.045122+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.045230+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.045325+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.045430+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.045559+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.045636+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.045733+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.045816+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.046389+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:205)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.046492+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.046569+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.046655+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.046703+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:180)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.046754+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.046799+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.046854+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.046917+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.046949+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:126)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.047006+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:93)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.047056+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.047155+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:52)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.047233+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:27)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.047303+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.047760+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8535df66@eu-cdbr-west-01.cleardb.com"'.
2015-12-18T22:31:12.047838+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.047913+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.047988+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.048085+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.048161+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.048230+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.048300+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.048372+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.048441+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:924)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.048554+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:870)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.048623+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:333)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.048706+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:92)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.048779+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:98)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.048851+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.addConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:438)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.048927+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool$1.run(BaseHikariPool.java:413)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.049058+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.049135+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.049207+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.049280+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.049352+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.049667+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8535df66@eu-cdbr-west-01.cleardb.com"
2015-12-18T22:31:12.049742+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.049816+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.049887+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.049965+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.port(NonRegisteringDriver.java:822)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.050039+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
2015-12-18T22:31:12.050120+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 9 more
2015-12-18T22:31:12.905287+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 255

the database url is something like (info [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb#configuring-your-ruby-application-to-use-cleardb)) and it's from clearDB:


slick.dbs.default.db.url = "jdbc:mysql://adffdadf2341:adf4234@us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com/heroku_db?reconnect=true"
```

As far as I've seen the same problem [happened long time ago](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/InNHhoWf82Q), with play 1.

I'm using play 2.4.4 and play-slick 1.1.0. Is it an error that was reintroduced? Or I'm I missing something? Is it a mysql driver (known) problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution on [play-framework mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/play-framework/DSJAr9SSKSU/CTonDNGzAwAJ)

sort answer:

> "it looks like the mysql jdbc driver is failing to parse the input string "8535...@eu-cdbr-west-01.cleardb.com”, and that doesn’t seem to originate from Play or play-slick"

final solution:

```
slick.dbs.default.driver = "slick.driver.MySQLDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url = "jdbc:mysql://eu-cdbr-west-01.cleardb.com/DATABASE"
slick.dbs.default.db.user = "USER"
slick.dbs.default.db.password = "PASS"
slick.dbs.default.db.connectionTimeout = 10 seconds
```

I know 10 seconds it's a lot, made it just for testing.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL driver is treating `adffdadf2341:adf4234@us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com` as `host:port`, so it's treating `adf4234@us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com` as the port number and trying to convert this to an integer.

If those are intended to be multiple hosts using default port number, replace ':' with ','.

Comment: nop, it's the mysql url provided by clearDB. Info here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb#configuring-your-ruby-application-to-use-cleardb

Comment: that link does not show the `jdbc:` prefix in the URL, and the logic for using the URL with JDBC is splitting on the ':', and with the `jdbc:` prefix, you've introduced another ':', which maybe causing issues with how it's parsed.

Comment: yes, the conf provided for slick is:

slick.dbs.default.db.url = "jdbc:mysql://b20f74bc500d6a:8535df66@eu-cdbr-west-01.cleardb.com/heroku_5adcda28b3b987e?reconnect=true"

so, is there any escape char or something?

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with ClearDB, have only used MySQL JDBC driver directly, but as far as I know, no escape char (at least for mysql).  If you haven't yet, may be worth a try dropping "jdbc:" from url and giving it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue is that your framework cannot swallow the mysql url whole. You need to parse it into its components (username, password, hostname, db name) and stuff them into the proper fields.